# Viewcontroller not conforming NSObject protocol

Tags: swift, xcode, nsobjectprotocol

I'm working on a app that was doing great so far. 
But today, maybe after some twinkering to try to implement a WatchOsKit, my viewcontroller seems to be broken.

Xcode is telling me that it's not conforming to the NSObject Protocol and that a bunch of methods are missing. 
[image: ViewController not conforming]
[image: The missing methods]

How can I fix this ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I'm self answering the question.

The problem was that I ticked the Apple Watch extension in the "target membership" window in the File Inspector, and for some reasons, it made XCode panic.

[image: Now that it's unchecked, everything is back to normal.]